# How to jun a jar file in Application Client Container in Jboss 7?

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

I need to run my jar file which contains some session beans. In EJB 3 book I saw we can run a main class using glassfish as follows.

appclient -client example-client.jar

How can I do this is JBoss 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar in JBoss AS 7. Should be something like `appclient.sh example-client.jar`. The [appclient documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Application+Client+Reference) doesn't look real complete, but there is some information specific to JBoss AS 7.